# ZMQ server doesn't see any messages

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm writing server using python and ZMQ. REQ-REP pattern. Sometimes, if the server crashes or restarts, then it stops seeing any messages sent to it at all. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q** : *What could be the problem?*

The nature of a principally unsafe, mutual-deadlock prone **distributed**-**F**inite-**S**tate-**A**utomaton is.

Given the `REP` dies during the `REQ` waiting for a response, deadlock
Given the `REQ` dies during the `REP` waiting for a request, chances are to restore `REQ/REP` quickstep
Given the `REQ` dies before the `REP` sends the response, deadlock
Given the `REQ` dies during the `REP` sending the response, deadlock
Given the `REP` dies before the `REQ` sending a request, chances are to restore `REQ/REP` quickstep

Comment: Can you please send link to know more about this, or number of chapter in zmq guide?